# How to render an asp.net WebForm page from Global.asax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, global-asax

for one reason or another I'm messing around with a "minimalistic" ASP.Net just for fun. I've disabled a lot of things and am attempting to reimplement things. One thing I can't quite figure out is how to render an ASP.Net page(aspx).

This is my progress so far:

```
//global.asax
    protected virtual void Application_BeginRequest (Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlTextWriter writer=new HtmlTextWriter(Response.Output);
        if(Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Substring(0,Math.Min(Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Length,8))=="/static/"){
            return; //let it just serve the static files
        }else if(Request.Url.AbsolutePath=="/test1"){
            test1 o=new test1();
            o.ProcessRequest(Context);
            o.RenderControl(writer);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
            Response.Flush();
        //  Response.Write(writer.ToString());

        }else{
            Response.ContentType="text/plain";
            Response.Write("Hi world!");
        }
        CompleteRequest();
    }
```

the /static/ bit works as does the "hi world". I can't get the `/test1` route to work though. It reaches that point but all that is displayed is a black page.

I have a test1.aspx page with this designer content:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="namespace.test1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>test1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1"> <!--just testing if two forms works and such-->

    </form>
    <form id="form2">
    <input type="text" id="test1" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and it has almost no code behind(just an empty function which doesn't matter)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

*Global.asax* is a red herring. ASP.NET is successfully rendering the page you requested:

```
test1 o=new test1();
```

`test1` is the code-behind class for the *test1.aspx* page. That's not what you want though, see? Everything you're expecting to see comes from the *test1.aspx* file. What you need to do is tell ASP.NET to render *test1.aspx* to Response.Output:

```
using (var o = (Page) BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath("/test1.aspx", typeof (Page))) {
    o.ProcessRequest(Context);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute` here. See [HttpServerUtility.Execute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.execute.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

My first thought would be that you do not call the hidden [Page.FrameworkInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56h09azw%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). I'm not sure that it actually does anything for you in this scenario.

I also believe that [Page.ProcessRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.processrequest.aspx) will render directly to the provided HttpContext. See ProcessRequestMain in Reflector, during Render it calls `this.RenderControl(this.CreateHtmlTextWriter(this.Response.Output))`.

We dont get to see where you get your Request and Response object from. Have you checked the HttpApplication sent to you as the `sender` parameter, so you're sure that you're using the correct objects?

Comment: yes they are the correct Request and Response objects, they are like built into the global.asax class

Answer (score 1):

This article shows [how to render a UserControl from a web service](http://jamesewelch.com/2008/07/11/how-to-render-a-aspnet-user-control-within-a-web-service-and-return-the-generated-html/). May be that can be of help.